# Histogram + dichotomous + axis

Tags: r, plot, histogram, axis

I'd like to make a histogram of my variable "sex" with the values 1 = male and 2 = female. My code works properly, but I'd like to have only the values 1 and 2 on the x-axis (at the moment R prints all values between 0 and 1 in steps which makes less sense in the case of sex).

```
hist(g1_sex, 
     main = "Häufigkeitsverteilung Geschlecht", 
     sub = "1 = männlich, 2 = weiblich",
     xlab = "Geschlecht", 
     ylab ="Häufigkeit",
     ylim = c(0,120),
     col = "lightblue",
     labels = TRUE,
     breaks=2)
```

[image: hist]

I already tried to do it with

```
breaks = seq (1,2,1)
```

but this doesn't look nice too.

I would be very thankful for every hint of you!
Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really want `barplot`. See examples:

```
set.seed(0); x <- rbinom(500, 1, 0.3)  ## generate toy 0-1 data
y <- table(x)   ## make contingency table
names(y) <- c("male", "female")
ylim = c(0, 1.2 * max(y))  ## set plotting range
z <- barplot(y, space = 0, col = 5, main = "statistics", ylim = ylim)
text(z, y + 20, y, cex = 2, col = 5)  ## add count number above each bar
```

I have also give solutions to add number above each bar, by setting extra space on the top using `ylim`, and use `text` to put texts.

[image: barplot]

Note that `barplot` also accepts `main`, etc, so you can add other annotations if you want.